# Forward environment variable to the post-build task

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

On my Jenkins server, I've installed [this extension](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task), which allows me to add a post-build task.

This task is basically a call to a `PowerShell` script. This powershell script needs to receive the branch and the build number as parameter.

I don't find how to transmit those, I tried this:

```
powershell -File D:\Scripts\postBuildScript.ps1 -branch ${Branch} -build ${Build_Number}
```

But then in the script I get `${Branch}`and `${Build_Number}` as value.

How can I forward those?

Comment: well, if that's cmd %branch% and %build_number%?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to reference the environment variables is by surrounding them with with percent characters:

```
powershell -File D:\Scripts\postBuildScript.ps1 -branch %BRANCH% -build %BUILD_NUMBER%
```

Alternatively I think you could also reference them within the PowerShell script itself via `$env:` for example:

```
Param(
   $branch = $env:branch,
   $build = $env:build_number
)
```

Comment: well, they would be gone by the time script starts, obviously